# How to turn off prettier replacing space with {' '} in formatter?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, prettier

Sometimes I write some space at the front of the `Text string`

e.g.

```
<Text>  something something</Text>
```

But after I format It. Prettier automatically convert it to

```
<Text>{' '} ... </Text>
```

Can I turn off this setting?

Comment: It looks like prettier only adds `{" "}` when it wraps the output on multiple lines. Is that the case on your side?

Comment: @EmileBergeron Yeah When I use prettier to format. Its ignore the space between strings but it will automatically add {` `} whenever there is space between string and html tag

Comment: In the [Prettier Playground](https://prettier.io/playground/), I see that it adds the space only if it ends up wrapping the lines. If the line is short enough and isn't wrapped, it doesn't have any `{" "}` added. Please include a [mcve] in your question, with the prettier version and configuration options used.

Comment: that is by design and the config provides no way to override this. if you don't want spaces between tags and text, not typing those spaces is your only bet. plus, if this was a thing, you'd have other issues like `a <span>bc</span>` rendering to `abc` instead of `a bc`. prettier is an opinionated formatter, so your choice is either use what it gives you or use another formatted.

Answer (score 1):

TLDR: You can't, there is no such option and they'll not add new options.

Prettier generally is built to be a set of configurations that should not be changed.

from their page: `Prettier is not a kitchen-sink code formatter that attempts to print your code in any way you wish. It is opinionated.`

https://prettier.io/docs/en/option-philosophy.html

This is their philosophy, prettier is best used by just sticking to the defaults.

If you want to customize how your code is formatted, you'll have to do the work yourself with eslint, for example

Comment: Quite astounding considering it completely destroys markup sometimes, rendering certain css-attributes like capitalize useless because the whitespace confuses the browser what words stick together etc. It will even add the JS ' ' when using things like &nbsp; - Opiniated is good, but there needs to be flexible ways to turn off things.

Comment: @Thorvald then prettier is not for you, you can try to find some eslint configurations that mimic prettier and customize them. There should be one out there somewhere